# Can I merge a time series iteratively in a loop?

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I'm trying to merge zoo classes within a loop, accumulating zoo series as new 'columns' with each iteration. I initialize an empty `zoo()` prior to running the loop. After my code completes, I get 'zoo series without observations' when I call `str()` on it. Yet, when I experiment with initializing an empty zoo, then merging it with itself and another instance with data, it works fine. The zoo in question below is '`monthlyReturns`' in the 2nd loop. Btw I do know I'd be better served using the apply family. That will be next. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(tseries)
library(zoo)
symbs = c('XLF', 'XLE', 'XLU', 'SPY')
importData = vector('list', length(symbs))
cumInvestmentReturns = zoo()
monthlyReturns = zoo()

#Get monthly pricing data.
for (sIdx in 1:length(symbs)){
    #Import the data for each symbol into the list.
    importData[sIdx] = get.hist.quote(instrument= symbs[sIdx], start="2000-01-01", end="2013-07-15", 
          quote="AdjClose", provider="yahoo", origin="1970-01-01", compression="m", retclass="zoo")
    names(importData[sIdx]) = symbs[sIdx]
}

#Loop over length of lookback months (1-12) to check for performance of best etf in past period.
for (numbOfMonths in 1:12){
    #Calculate performances on each symbol, using the lookback length of variable numbOfMonths.
    monthlyPctChgs = lapply(importData, function(x) diff(x, lag =numbOfMonths) / lag(x, k=-numbOfMonths))
    names(monthlyPctChgs) = symbs

    #combine all ticker time series into one time series.
    tsPctChgs = merge(monthlyPctChgs[[1]], monthlyPctChgs[[2]], monthlyPctChgs[[3]], monthlyPctChgs[[4]], 
          monthlyPctChgs[[5]], monthlyPctChgs[[6]], monthlyPctChgs[[7]], monthlyPctChgs[[8]], 
          monthlyPctChgs[[9]], monthlyPctChgs[[10]], monthlyPctChgs[[11]], monthlyPctChgs[[12]])
    names(tsPctChgs) = symbs

    curBestLagPerfs <- rollapplyr(tsPctChgs, 2, function(x) x[2,which.max(x[1,])], by.column=FALSE)
    monthlyReturns = merge(monthlyReturns, curBestLagPerfs)
    #finalSet = finalSet[2:length(finalSet$SPY),] #Remove first value, since there is an na.

    lookbackReturns = cumprod(1+curBestLag) * 10000
    cumInvestmentReturns = merge(cumInvestmentReturns, lookbackReturns)
    #names(investmentsPaired) = c('SPY', 'ETFRotation')
}
```

Comment: You ask several questions here to know that we need a reproductible example to help you. For example simplifying your code just enough to reproduce the behavior and giving code to get the data through `tseries::get.hist.quote` and providing `symbs` object for example will be perfect.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand everything that's going on in the code, but I think you probably want `importData[[sIdx]]` in both places in the first loop. (i.e. `[[` instead of `[`)  You'll also probably be interested to know that your giant merge in the second loop could be replaced with `do.call(merge, monthlyPctChgs)`. However, I'm not sure it's doing what you think it is; it looks like your code is making the assumption that `NROW(symbs) == 12`.

Comment: I just provided symbs, I knew better... thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid this kind of error and implement efficient code in R, you have to learn how to use function like lapply, apply and others *apply. There's an excellent post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Here is my simplification of your code, not fully tested but it will give insight on how you can improve your code and correct some errors.

```
require(tseries)
require(zoo)
symbs <- c('XLF', 'XLE', 'XLU', 'SPY')

importData <- lapply(symbs, function(symb)
                     get.hist.quote(instrument= symb,
                                    start = "2000-01-01",
                                    end = "2013-07-15", 
                                    quote="AdjClose", provider = "yahoo",
                                    origin="1970-01-01", compression = "m",
                                    retclass="zoo"))

names(importData) <- symbs


monthlyPctChgs <- lapply(1:12, function(y)
                         lapply(importData,
                                function(x) diff(x, lag = y) / lag(x, lag = - y)))


tsPctChgs <- lapply(monthlyPctChgs, do.call, what = merge)


curBestLagPerfs <- lapply(tsPctChgs, function(y)
                          rollapplyr(y, 2,
                                     function(x) x[2,which.max(x[1,])],
                                     by.column=FALSE))

curBestLagPerfs <- do.call(merge, curBestLagPerfs)
names(curBestLagPerfs) <- month.abb
str(curBestLagPerfs)
## ‘zoo’ series from 2000-03-01 to 2013-06-03
##   Data: num [1:160, 1:12] 0.09156 0.00933 -0.00229 -0.06095 -0.01496 ...
##  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
##   ..$ : NULL
##   ..$ : chr [1:12] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" ...
##   Index:  Date[1:160], format: "2000-03-01" "2000-04-03" "2000-05-01" ...
```

Hope it will help

Comment: btw i did mention in my post the understanding that apply was far better form.

Comment: @StatsViaCsh Yes you're right and I'll encourage you to perfect your understanding of *apply mechanism in R. You'll save a lot of time.